# How to add array to vue-kanban blocks

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm implementing vue-kanban component in my web application. There I'd like to display some objects from my database but I need some help to add them to the kanban board.

This is my array with the projects:

```
props: {
  projects: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  }
},
```

And here I'd like to add them to the kanban board, it should be instead of `blocks`:

```
data() {
  return {
    stages: ['open', 'doing', 'close'],
    blocks: [
      {
        id: 1,
        status: 'open',
        title: 'test',
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

I use that component: https://github.com/BrockReece/vue-kanban

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add template code which you've tried.

Comment: In `mounted` try setting `this.blocks` to `this.projects || []` ? `this.blocks = this.projects || []` or See this answer for initialising the data property to props. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408096/whats-the-correct-way-to-pass-props-as-initial-data-in-vue-js-2

Comment: @FrancisLeigh how exactly should the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

See [What's the correct way to pass props as initial data in Vue.js 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408096/whats-the-correct-way-to-pass-props-as-initial-data-in-vue-js-2)

If the Kanban component is expecting an attribute like `:blocks="[...]"` and nothing is going to happen to the data can you not pass the `projects` array directly to it? e.g `:blocks="projects"`

If no and the data name `blocks` is a must and the data needs to be mutable then see below.

```js
export default {
  name: "YourComponent",
  props: {
    projects: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      blocks: this.projects
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work... also got no error in the console so I don't know what's wrong

Comment: As I said, there is no error in the console, so I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: @carl can you update your question with the whole component or maybe a Github Gist.