# Using v-select dropdown for default value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have a dropdown using the v-select component and setting my options as "US" and "CANADA".

I want to set the default value (`:value`)to read off of `customer.country_code`, which is set to "US" in this case but it doesn't have the preloaded selection.  I have use v-select in similar instances but not sure what I'm messing up here.

```
<v-select
   :options="['US', 'CA']"                                   
   :value="customer.country_code"                                       
   v-model="defaultCountry"
</v-select>
```

The v-model `defaultCountry` is initiated like this:

```
data() {
   return {
       defaultCountry: null
  }
},

props: {
    customer: { type: Object }
}
```

The customer.country_code is a prop so I can't instantiate the v-model to that value.

Comment: make `defaultCountry` equal `customer.country_code`

Comment: `v-model` should control the value, not `:value`

Comment: at what point do I make defaultCountry equal to that?  I don't believe the prop is accessible at the `data() { } ` point

Comment: it is, you can just use `defaultCountry: this.props.customer.country_code`

Comment: @DerekPollard weirdddd -- it doesn't work as `defaultCountry: this.props.customer.country_code` but works as `defaultCountry: this._props.customer.country_code` .  Why would that be??

Comment: That is really odd, it should work like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435856/2020002

Comment: I put a `debugger` in the data() section and in console, I typed `this._` and the options are `this._isMounted`, `this._isVue`, `this._props`, `this_self`, `this._watcher`, and a few others.  Even trying to type `this.props` autocorrects to `this._props`.  Trying `this.props` comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

v-select as in vuetify component?

your v-model should have the value 'US' and that will be the first selected item

Comment: yea, vuetify component -- sorry.  I am going to edit my question with a reply^

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdown.vue:

<select v-model="country">
  <option value="0">US</option>
  <option value="1">CANADA</option>
</select>

dropdown.js

In data declare this v-model.
country: 0

Then the default value "US" will be preselected in dropdown.

This is my first answer on stack overflow..hope it helps. ThankYou
```