# Initialising data from an object prop in a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two Vue components, `EventTask` and `EventCard`. `EventTask` has a `currentEvent` object in `data`, which I pass as a prop to `EventCard` like so

```html
<event-card :current-event="currentEvent" />
```

In EventCard, I initialise an `event` data property from the `currentEvent` prop, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911153/4786956)

```
export default {
  name: 'EventCard',
  props: {
    currentEvent: {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      event: { ...this.currentEvent }
    }
  }
}
```

However, for some reason, the `event` data property is not being set correctly. Here's what I see in the Vue developer tools

[image]

Notice that the `currentEvent` prop is an object with a  with a bunch of properties, but the `event` data property is an empty object. Why is the data property not being initialised correctly from the prop?

Comment: Can you share a simple demo/fiddle representing your scenario, because it works in normal cases.

Comment: why do you need to create another property in data? you can use the same currentEvent (this.currentEvent) in your EventCard component. Any specific reason for creating another property in data?.

The other way is to assign the currentEvent to event (in data) in one of the life cycles, you can use mounted() {this.event = this.currentEvent }

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty I need to create another property in data because I will be modifying this object in the `EventCard` component, but I don't want these changes to propogate to the  `EventTask` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can occur if `currentEvent` is updated *after* `EventCard` has already initialized. Note that `data()` is not invoked reactively, so changes to `currentEvent` would not re-initialize `event`.

One solution is to use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `currentEvent` to copy it to `event`:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    currentEvent(newValue) {
      this.event = { ...newValue }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/watching-a-prop-in-vue-xue1g?file=/src/components/EventCard.vue)

Comment: I think `currentEvent` being updated after `EventCard` has initialized is exactly what the problem is. I didn't realise that `data()` is invoked only once, rather than reactively.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code

```
export default {
  name: 'EventCard',
  props: {
    currentEvent: {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      event: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.event = this.currentEvent // you can also try clone here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this instead:

```
export default {
  name: 'EventCard',
  props: {
    currentEvent: {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      event: this.currentEvent
    }
  }
}
```

Source : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: AFAIK, it's recommended that you *don't* do this when the prop is an object or array (which are passed by reference), because changes in the child will also be reflected in the parent. Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435856/2648

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the info