# Input element's value filtering from inside parent component - Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having trouble to figure out how to update an input element's value from the parent accurately. Below I have a simplified code to explain my problem more clearly. Hope someone can give me a hand to solve this in a correct way!

ParentComponent:

```
<script setup>
const form = useForm({
  payment_number: '',
});

const cardNumberChecker = value => {
  const cleaned = value.toString().replace(/\D/g, '');
  const trimmed = cleaned.slice(0, 16);
  const grouped = trimmed ? trimmed.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(' ') : '';

  updateCardNumber.value++; // Current fix
  form.payment_number = grouped;
};
<script>
<template>
    <InputComponent
    :update="updateCardNumber" // Current fix
    :text="form.payment_number"
    @input-trigger="cardNumberChecker"
    ></InputComponent>
</template>
```

InputComponent:

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  update: { type: Number, default: 0 }, // Current fix
  text: { type: String, default: '' },
});

defineEmits(['input-trigger']);
</script>
<template>
    <input
    :value="text"=
    type="text"
    @input="$emit('input-trigger', $event.target.value)"
    />
</template>
```

On input event, `cardNumberChecker` is filtering and cleaning the input value. The issue is when a character inserted is not allowed, thus not changing `form.payment_number` variable and hence not updating the InputComponent causing to allow the keyboard inputted character to show in the input field anyway.

As a temporary fix I have added a counter that increments on each keyboard input to cause the InputComponent to rerender.

Is there a proper Vue way to sort this out? Thank you!

Comment: I think the best way is to copy your prop into a data variable. Use this data variable a v-model on your input field. This will rerender on this v-model

Comment: @Wimanicesir can you elaborate a bit more please? I got this error when I tried to save the prop in a variable: Getting a value from the `props` in root scope of `<script setup>` will cause the value to lose reactivity

Comment: I think you didn't define your data correctly. I would advise to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408096/whats-the-correct-way-to-pass-props-as-initial-data-in-vue-js-2

Comment: @Wimanicesir thanks but still doesn't work for me. I added the following inside InputComponent and referenced `data` in the input's :value attribute

```let data = ref('');

onMounted(() => {
  data.value = props.text;
});
```
No input/text shows in the field.